# How to use Wowza media server with Jack Audio Connection Kit as input on MAC OS?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, rtsp, wowza, jack

I need to live broadcast multiple RTSP streams out of the audio mixing software StudioOne. For this I am using Jack Audio Connection Kit as the connector. I've already tried using IceCast with Darkice but the latency went up to 6+ seconds which won't work for the project that I'm working on. That's why I'm using the Wowza media server which does RTSP streaming instead of HTTP.

That's where I'm stuck as I need some way of getting the streams from Jack Audio to Wowza on a MAC OS machine. I've tried using FFMpeg but FFMpeg doesn't have the feature to get input from Jack Audio on it's OSX version. I can try to port my whole setup onto an Ubuntu but the mixing software StudioOne isn't available on Ubuntu. I can try using Wine to port StudioOne to Linux but I'm not sure it'll be a good idea for real time mixer to be used as a port, especially when latency is involved.

Is there some other way I can get input from Jack Audio to Wowza Media Server on my MAC?

Comment: JACK is supported on OSX now in FFmpeg

Comment: Was this added recently? I wasn't able to get it working. Jack is always disabled in FFMPEG for OSX no matter how I compile it. Can you give me instructions on how to compile FFMPEG with Jack on OSX?

Comment: it was recently added, you need to have jack already installed in order for it to be enabled. make sure to use the latest git

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Modified the homebrew formula to compile it with the latest run and with jack enabled. Please enter this as an answer so I can mark it as one.

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JACK on OS X is now in FFmpeg as of [this commit (67f8a0be545)](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=67f8a0be54554715a93a4e288da3247c9a5d4e1c).

Once you have JACK installed, you can [compile FFmpeg from source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX) and support should be automatically compiled into FFmpeg.